# Insert variable in "open in new window" link

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var affglcid = 'xyz';
</script>

<a href="http://oursite.com/" onclick="location.href=this.href+affglcid;return false;">Link</a>
```

It basically takes a JS variable and appends it to a link.

So, if the variable is:

```
var affglcid = 'xyz';
```

The final link will be:

> http://oursite.com/xyz

If the variable is:

```
var affglcid = 'zyz';
```

The final link will be:

> http://oursite.com/zyx

It works almost perfectly. Problem is that when we open the link in an external window the URL is always

> http://oursite.com/

Without the variable appended. What can we do so the scripts appends the variable even when the link is opened in a new window?

Comment: because you're doing this for `onclick` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set href on page load because when open in new window, onclick not called

```
<script>
window.onload = function setHref(){
var aa = 'xyz';
var oldLink=document.getElementById('link').href;
document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('href', oldLink+aa);
}
</script>
<a id="link" href="http://oursite.com/">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks bro! 

I'm trying to do it with two links, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea?

<script>
window.onload = function setHref(){
var affglcid = <?php echo json_encode($kws); ?>;

var oldLink=document.getElementById('link').href;
document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('href', oldLink+affglcid);

var oldLink1=document.getElementById('link2').href;
document.getElementById('link2').setAttribute('href', oldLink1+affglcid);
}
</script>


<a id="link" href="http://oursite.com/">Link</a>

<a id="link2" href="http://othersite.com/">Link</a>

Comment: Yes, it works for one link but I forgot to mention I need two :) Thanks for your help! I opened a new thread anyway. If you feel like it, give it a look!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911503/append-a-javascript-variable-to-two-html-links