# Append a Javascript variable to two HTML links

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have the following scripts:

```
<script> 
window.onload = function setHref(){ 
var affglcid = <?php echo json_encode($kws); ?>; 

var oldLink=document.getElementById('link').href; 
document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('href', oldLink+affglcid); 

var oldLink1=document.getElementById('link2').href; 
document.getElementById('link2').setAttribute('href', oldLink1+affglcid); 
}
</script>
```

And:

```
<a id="link" href="oursite.com/">Link</a>
<a id="link2" href="othersite.com/">Link</a>
```

First, it takes a PHP variable:

```
var affglcid = <?php echo json_encode($kws); ?>;
```

Then it appends the variable at the end of a link:

```
var oldLink=document.getElementById('link').href; 
document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('href', oldLink+affglcid);
```

It should do the same for another link:

```
var oldLink1=document.getElementById('link2').href;
document.getElementById('link2').setAttribute('href', oldLink1+affglcid);
```

So, if $kw=xy then the first link should be "oursite.com/xy" and the second one "othersite.com/xy" but it only works on the other site link. The code used for that is the following:

```
<a id="link" href="oursite.com/">Link</a>
<a id="link2" href="othersite.com/">Link</a
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that your URLs not correct, they should start with "http://" or "https://"

```
<a id="link" href="http://oursite.com/">Link</a>
<a id="link2" href="http://othersite.com/">Link</a>
```

Even if you don't want to add protocol, you should atleast use //oursite.com, otherwise it'll be considered as relative URL which will append this URL in front of your current URL and try to open that

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot bro :)